# ActiveRecord get Rating Winner Websites for Award of a specific time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There is a `Website` model which has_many `Rating`s with a `score` attribute.

To determine the **top 10 winner websites** i could just calculate and cache the `total_score` on the Website record and order after that.

Unfortunately it's not that easy - i need to determine the winner for an award in a specific time frame. It can be rated before and after the award time period.

How would i do that? Group by and then order by count (which is not working - see below)? i guess it has around 1.000 website records with 100.000 ratings total...

```
Website.left_joins(:ratings).group('ratings.website_id').
        where(ratings: { created_at: Time.parse('2019-01-01')..Time.parse('2019-06-01') }).
        order('count(ratings.score) desc').
        limit(10)
```

Or create something like a snapshot of that period?

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Comment: You said "determine the winner for an award in a SPECIFIC TIME FRAME"? But I don't see your sample code is querying against this time frame? If you just forgot to do so, what is this "time frame" gonna be queried upon? i.e. `created_at`? or `updated_at`? Or  do you meant to just cache results (winners) for this specific time frame? If so, what's an example of this specific time frame query?

Comment: sorry i totally forgot - just updated the question. its based on `ratings.created_at`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If without Joins / Subqueries:

i.e. if you're only retrieving Top 10 (only few) websites, and not thousands of `website` records, or that you are not gonna iterate each in the thousands of arrays.

```
ratings = Rating.where(
  created_at: Time.parse('2019-01-01')..Time.parse('2019-06-01')
).group(
  :website_id
).order(
  'sum(score) desc'
).select(
  :website_id
)

top_10_winner_websites = ratings.take(10).map(&:website)
# above is ordered by sum(score) desc
# so,
# top_10_winner_websites[0] has the highest sum score, while
# top_10_winner_websites[-1] has the lowest sum score amongst the 10
```

***Caution:*** note that query above is only "selecting" `ratings.website_id`, and not `ratings.*` which would mean that the other attributes (like `id` and `score`) of `ratings` objects would be all `nil`, only except `website_id`

### If with Joins / Subqueries:

**Edit: TODO below does not full work yet; might need help. Couldn't find/solve a way to preserve ordering of `website_id` outside the subquery. Got busy at the moment.**

To prevent N+1 queries if you are gonna iterate each `website` record, or that if you are gonna retrieve thousands of `website` records.

```
top_10_winner_websites = Website.where(
  id: Rating.where(
    created_at: Time.parse('2019-01-01')..Time.parse('2019-06-01')
  ).group(
    :website_id
  ).order(
    'sum(ratings.score) desc'
  ).select(
    'website_id r'
  )
).limit(10).order('r.website_id asc')
```

#### Current Workaround (for unfinished subquery above):

*as workaround to solve "preserving ordering" outside the subquery, while prevent N+1 queries:*

```
ratings = Rating.where(
  created_at: Time.parse('2019-01-01')..Time.parse('2019-06-01')
).group(
  :website_id
).order(
  'sum(ratings.score) desc'
).select(
  :website_id
)

top_10_winner_website_ids = ratings.take(10).map(&:website_id)

top_10_winner_websites = Website.where(
  id: top_10_winner_website_ids
).sort_by do |website|
  top_10_winner_website_ids.index(website.id)
end
```

**Edit: Per extended request, you can check and get the rank of website:**

```
website_to_check = Website.find(1)

index = top_10_winner_websites.index{|winner_website| winner_website.id == website_to_check.id }

if index.nil?
  puts 'Website was not part of the top 10 winners in this time period'
else
  puts "Website rank for this time period was: #{index + 1}"
end
```

^ If you want a pure SQL rank-checker for this, I'm not too sure how to implement it.

**Edit: Per extended request to have extra "conditions" for the `Website` records:**

...you can still use `joins(:website)` but this does not prevent N+1 queries compared to `eager_load(:website)` or `includes(:website)` but eager loading does not seem to work because of a `PG::GroupingError`, but you can still prevent the N+1 queries using workaround above. See full example below:

```
ratings = Rating.joins(:website).where(
  created_at: Time.parse('2019-01-01')..Time.parse('2019-06-01'),
  websites: {
    some_website_attribute_1: true, # UPDATE THIS
    some_website_attribute_2: 'foobar' # UPDATE THIS
  }
).group(
  :website_id
).order(
  'sum(ratings.score) desc'
).select(
  :website_id
)

top_10_winner_website_ids = ratings.take(10).map(&:website_id)

top_10_winner_websites = Website.where(
  id: top_10_winner_website_ids
).sort_by do |website|
  top_10_winner_website_ids.index(website.id)
end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194819/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-ar-polidario-activerecord-get-rating-winner-websites).